# Python OpenCV OCR digit array not printing in order with for loop

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I have what may be a simple issue in some ~55 lines of code for Python 2.7 OCR for handwritten digits. I obtained this code from a blog and am using it for hobby purposes. I am utilizing cv2, sklearn, skimage, and numpy to assist in the digit recognition.

I have a simple question for the code here - at the end of the for loop I append the number that is "recognized" from sklearn to a numpy array. This works fine, however, the numbers are all out of order. For example, if an image I upload has handwritten "9 8 7 5 4 3" it will print as [5, 4, 3, 9, 7, 8]

I've been staring at this for a while and I can't seem to figure out why it is looping "out of order." I don't know if that is how OpenCV is detecting the numbers, or if it is a function of sklearn - or just a simple logic issue.

Here is the code (the issue I'm having is at the very end - appending to array):

```
# Import the modules
import cv2
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from skimage.feature import hog
import numpy as np

# Load the classifier
clf = joblib.load("digits_cls.pkl")

# Read the input image 
im = cv2.imread("4.jpg")

# Convert to grayscale and apply Gaussian filtering
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (5, 5), 0)


# Threshold the image
ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)


cv2.imshow("Threshhold/gray", im_th)

# Find contours in the image
hier, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get rectangles contains each contour
rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in ctrs]

# For each rectangular region, calculate HOG features and predict
# the digit using Linear SVM.

numlist = []
for rect in rects:
    # Draw the rectangles
    cv2.rectangle(im, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + 
    rect[3]), (0, 255, 0), 3)
    # Make the rectangular region around the digit
    leng = int(rect[3] * 1.6)
    pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
    pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)
    roi = im_th[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]
    # Resize the image
    roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    roi = cv2.dilate(roi, (3, 3))
    # Calculate the HOG features
    roi_hog_fd = hog(roi, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(14, 14), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=False)
    nbr = clf.predict(np.array([roi_hog_fd], 'float64'))
    cv2.putText(im, str(int(nbr[0])), (rect[0], rect[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 255), 3)


    # Appending output to array for further processing
    number = (int(nbr[0]))
    numlist.append(number)

print numlist

cv2.imshow("Resulting Image with Rectangular ROIs", im)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort rects by x value before ocr.

```
rects = sorted(rects, key = lambda rect: rect[0] + rect[2]//2)
```